# Can/Should I mix application/x-ndjson with application/hal+json?

Tags: http, http-headers, reactive-programming, hateoas

Currently trying to get the best of both worlds in the same http response, but an http response can have only one content type.

Should I use one content type for both?
Is this not encouraged/recommended?

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT 2021-08-23 14:27Z**

This is the type of response I want to return, for which I don't know which Content-Type to use:

```
{ "firstname" : "Alan", "id" : 21, "_links" : { "self" : { "href" : "http://hos/people/21", "all" : { "href" : "http://hos/people" }, "dogs" : { "href" : "http://hos/people/21/dogs"  } }
{ "firstname" : "Dave", "id" : 42, "_links" : { "self" : { "href" : "http://hos/people/42", "all" : { "href" : "http://hos/people" }, "dogs" : { "href" : "http://hos/people/42/dogs"  } }
{ "firstname" : "John", "id" : 99, "_links" : { "self" : { "href" : "http://hos/people/99", "all" : { "href" : "http://hos/people" }, "dogs" : { "href" : "http://hos/people/99/dogs"  } }
```

`"best of both worlds"`:

I don't know a lot of both content types, but as I understand `application/x-ndjson` means each item is delimited with `\n`, and http clients can use this response an item at a time, or in bulk, but do not need to wait for the whole response to be built/sent to use it.

And `application/hal+json` as I understand means the returned json has links referencing available actions for the returned entity.

Comment: "best of both worlds in the same http response" tells us nothing. What exactly is in the response? Can you show a toy sample? Is it just a concatenation of a NDJSON and a JSON? Then you don't even have a JSON - it's `text/plain`.

Comment: Your response (as a whole) can be parsed as NDJSON, but not as JSON (and not as HAL+JSON): you would get a syntax error at the start of the second line. Thus, `application/x-ndjson` is correct, and `application/hal+json` would not be correct.